# Cannot connect to postgres docker container from golang's docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, go-gorm

I'm trying to connect to the docker container's postgresdb database from Golang Fibers container. When I run my postgres continer and run go project locally it could connect to the postgres's container but if I try to connect from golang's container it couldn't connect. It says connection refused. I've checked the network. It could resolve the host properly but why I cannot connect to the database I'm not sure. Can anyone help me ? My project's code is given below.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      my_network:
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - nim_auth_postgres

  nim_auth_postgres:
    container_name: nim_auth_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=nim_auth_db
    networks:
      my_network:

networks:
  my_network:
```

**Go Code**

```golang
package config

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

func DbConnection(){
    var err error
    dsn := "host=nim_auth_postgres user=postgres password=postgres dbname=nim_auth_db port=5433 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Dhaka"
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Dev.Dockerfile**

```yaml
FROM golang:1.21-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

CMD ["air", "-c", ".air.toml"]
```

The error I get once I start the service is:

```bash
web                | 2023/09/22 09:17:45 /app/src/config/connect_postgres_database.go:13
web                | [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=nim_auth_postgres user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 172.27.0.2:5433: connect: connection refused)
web                | panic: failed to connect to `host=nim_auth_postgres user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 172.27.0.2:5433: connect: connection refused)
web                | 
web                | goroutine 1 [running]:
web                | github.com/fahad-md-kamal/numbus-authenticator/src/config.DbConnection()
web                |    /app/src/config/connect_postgres_database.go:16 +0x10e
web                | main.main()
web                |    /app/main.go:10 +0xf
```

**Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc**

**Docker Compose version v2.20.3**

**go version go1.21.1 linux/amd64**

Comment: maybe the db is not yet ready to accept connection? See https://laurent-bel.medium.com/waiting-for-postgresql-to-start-in-docker-compose-c72271b3c74a

Comment: If I restart the go container it still the same error.

Comment: what about the status of the db? anything in the logs of the container of the database?

Comment: It's ready to accept requests.

Comment: You're using the wrong port number 5433.  Connections between containers neither use nor require `ports:`.  Does the standard PostgreSQL port 5432 work better?

Comment: I'm mapping the port `5433:5432` of postgres continer on docker-compose. Therefore, I'm trying to connect it on that port.

Comment: Strange....!! Eventhough my port is mapped to 5433 when I changed to port to 5432 of GORM it connected. It's like screw the port and go with old. :)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion. Though, I still don't understand why it's working. :(

Comment: You are inside the docker network and exposing ports has only effect from outside of docker network. For 5433 you would need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach dependant on which OS you are using

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in your Go code and corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file, the `DbConnection` string indicates `host=nim_auth_postgres` -- the application driver will attempt to look for a host with `hostname = nim_auth_postgres`, which exists only within the docker network.  Within the docker network, you refer to services with their internal port (`5432` in this case), not the external-facing port (`5433`, as indicated by the `ports:` section of `docker-compose.yml`).

Therefore you should use the following for your `dsn`:

```
dsn := "host=nim_auth_postgres user=postgres password=postgres dbname=nim_auth_db port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Dhaka"
```